# Delete an RODC in Active Directory via command line

Tags: active-directory

I know we can delete an RODC in Active Directory via DSA.msc. However, was just curious if we can do that through command line?

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You want to use ntdsutil to perform a [metadata cleanup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736378%28WS.10%29.aspx).